# GROUP BY clause in SQL code

Tags: sql, group-by

I created a table named `HOSTEL(hostel_num NUMBER, num_of_stud NUMBER)` and I inserted values as :

```
-------------------------- 
hostel_num | num_of_stud  |
--------------------------
1001       |    124       |
1001       |    234       |
1002       |     97       |
1002       |    134       |
1003       |    234       |
1004       |    123       |
1004       |     89       |
1001       |     67       |
--------------------------
```

When I applied `GROUP BY` command as :

```
SELECT hostel_num, sum(num_of_stud) as total_students 
FROM HOSTELS 
GROUP BY hostel_num;
```

, and I got the result as:

```
-----------------------------
hotel_num   | total_students |
-----------------------------
1003        |      234       |
1001        |      425       |
1002        |      231       |
1004        |      212       |
-----------------------------
```

Now, my question is: Why the `hostel_num 1003` came at the top ? Shouldn't it come at row number 3 ? What is the logic behind this kind of order ?

I know, that `GROUP BY` clause consolidates the repetitive column values and group them together.

My doubt is: How it decides the order of displaying those values, as here, I was expecting an output like this :

```
-----------------------------
hotel_num   | total_students |
-----------------------------
1001        |      425       |
1002        |      231       |
1003        |      234       |
1004        |      212       |
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an `ORDER BY`, no order is guaranteed:

```
SELECT hostel_num, sum(num_of_stud) as total_students 
FROM HOSTELS 
GROUP BY hostel_num
ORDER BY hostel_num;
```

Comment: If u are trying to say that it randomly picks the order, then I would say, I executed the command 3-4 times, and everytime it showed the same order. If it randomly picks the order, then the output must have been different next time. But the output didn't change.

Comment: As I love to tell, ordering is an illusion without an ORDER BY. Often you see the rows ordered by the primary key (because it's a cluster index), but sometimes you don't :-) This happens quite often if you have multiple servers in cluster and they subdivide the query between them.

Comment: @Rubbal Bhusri : That's not what I said. The query executor can return results in any order, if an explicit ORDER BY is not present. Period. The fact they come out in a particular order is down to how the query plan of execution was determined.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Order By`

```
SELECT  hostel_num ,
        SUM(num_of_stud) AS total_students
FROM    HOSTELS
GROUP BY hostel_num
ORDER BY hostel_num
```

See [Order By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) explanation.

**EDIT**: 
There's a [very good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938234/why-does-sql-server-2008-order-when-using-a-group-by-and-no-order-has-been-speci) to what you are seeing, take a look at this also.

Comment: If u are trying to say that it randomly picks the order, then I would say, I executed the command 3-4 times, and everytime it showed the same order. If it randomly picks the order, then the output must have been different next time. But the output didn't change.

Comment: I know the ORDER BY clause, But I wanted to know the behaviour of GROUP BY clause more deeply.

Comment: @RubbalBhusri, I can't see where I specify **random**, I'm just saying you need to include `Order By` to tell **SQL** which field to order by.  You can also append `ASC` or `DESC` to the end to flip the way it is ordered.

Comment: `Group By` will simply group your data into the **'buckets'** you specify, you're then responsible for specifying the order to display the records.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what order you want as i think if you dont specify any order by clause it decides on its own.

```
SELECT  hostel_num ,
    SUM(num_of_stud) AS total_students
 FROM    HOSTELS
GROUP BY hostel_num
ORDER BY hostel_num
```

Comment: If u are trying to say that it randomly picks the order, then I would say, I executed the command 3-4 times, and everytime it showed the same order. If it randomly picks the order, then the output must have been different next time. But the output didn't change.

Comment: I said its decided by sql server and didnt said it randomly decides order

Comment: I didn't want any specific order, rather I wanted to know, what is the logic behind selecting the order by 'GROUP BY' clause.

Comment: @Rubbal Bhusri : " I was expecting an output like this :" - how is that "I didn't want any specific order" ?

Comment: @MitchWheat are you asking anything to me?

Answer (score 0):

[Ben Forta](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135182794) conspicuously states the following saying.

> More often than not, you will find that data grouped using GROUP BY
>   will indeed be output in group order. But that is not always the case,
>   and it is not actually required by the SQL specifications.
>   Furthermore, even if your particular DBMS does, in fact, always sort
>   the data by the specified `GROUP BY` clause, you might actually want it
>   sorted differently. Just because you group data one way (to obtain
>   group-specific aggregate values) does not mean that you want the
>   output sorted that same way. You should always provide an explicit
>   `ORDER BY` clause as well, even if it is identical to the `GROUP BY`
>   clause.
>
> **Tip:**
>
> #### Don’t Forget *ORDER BY*
>
> As a rule, anytime you use a `GROUP BY` clause, you should also specify
>   an `ORDER BY` clause. That is the only way to ensure that data will be
>   sorted properly. Never rely on `GROUP BY` to sort your data.