# SQL Server 2008 R2 returning inconsistent results

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2

This query returns results that aren't grouped in the way the query expects it to. This started only happening recently and has been occurring  at least twice a week.

```
    SELECT 
       UserN, Program, CPair, PosCcy1,  OpenPosOpt,  CrossR,
       OptPrem, DailyOptValue, OptPandL
    FROM (
      (SELECT 
          UserN, Program, CPair,PosCcy1,OpenPosOpt,RevalC1, 
          RevalC2, CrossR, OptPrem,DailyOptValue,OptValue, OptPandL
         FROM 
             (SELECT  
                 UserN, Program, CPair, 
                 ROUND(SUM(Ccy1Amount),4) AS PosCcy1, 
                 ROUND(SUM(OpenOptPos),4) AS OpenPosOpt, 
                 MAX(RevalC1) as RevalC1, 
                 MAX(RevalC2) as RevalC2, 
                 case when MAX(RevalC2) = 0 and MAX(RevalC1) = 0 then 0
                      else MAX(RevalC2)/MAX(RevalC1) end as CrossR,
                 ROUND(SUM(OptPrem),2) AS OptPrem, 
                 ROUND(SUM(DailyOp),4) AS DailyOptValue, 
                 ROUND(SUM(OptValue),4) AS OptValue, 
                 ROUND(SUM(OpPandL),4) AS OptPandL,
                 sum(Prem) as Prem    
              FROM   
                 AReport rr  
              GROUP BY  
                 UserN, Program, CPair) a  
         WHERE  
            not(PosCcy1= 0  and  OpenPosOpt= 0 and  Prem  = 0)
 )) results
```

The 'AReport' is a  view.

As could be seen I expect the query to return the data grouped by User, Program and CPair. Almost always I get that result, but all of a sudden at times the results aren't grouped like that.

When this happens SQL Server returns the un-grouped results the whole day. I've  run parts of the query on SSMS during then and the results I get are grouped as expected for the two inner nested selects. The moment I highlight the outer most select to be included the results set is un-grouped.

I've looked for errors in the error log and the event viewer which doesn't seem to suggest anything. This behaviour is automatically rectified by the following day. Could someone tell me if there's anything in the way the query is written that's causing this behaviour.

Comment: I misunderstood the result set from being ordered and un-grouped.  When the query was run 99% of the time results were grouped and also ordered which got me confused when the results were not ordered suddenly. I began to think it wasn't getting grouped, where as they were only not getting ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that the inconsistency was the data displayed was almost always  ordered in the desired way . See [Why does SQL Server 2008 order when using a GROUP BY and no order has been specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938234/why-does-sql-server-2008-order-when-using-a-group-by-and-no-order-has-been-speci)

Adding an order by to the query fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189822.aspx
and review your query